# Image expression in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I've been just approaching to Google Earth Engine and JavaScript.
I am trying to write a code for chlorophyll-a concentration retrieval from Sentinel-2 images.
I want to obtain the chl-a from the atmospherically corrected images (level 2A) over a specific area of interest.
Since I want to do it for a collection I thought to write a function that work on a single image using image.expression and then pass it through the collection with the ".map" function.
The algorithm though seems to don't perform well,of course it would need a calibration but I am pretty sure that since I don't know how to neither GEE nor JS I am probably making tons of mistakes.
The formula that I want to implement is the following:
[image]

Where Rrs is the remote sensing reflectance, which means I have to divide every pixel value by pi.
442 is the band 1, 492 is the band 2 and finally 560 is band 3.
This is the code I am trying to write:

```
function chl_oc2(image) {
var Rrs= image.divide(Math.PI);
var x= Rrs.expression('log10(blue/green)',{'blue':Rrs.select('B3'),'green':Rrs.select('B2')});
var chl_conc=Rrs.expression('10**(0.2389-1.9369*x+1.7627*x**2-3.077*x**3-0.1054*x**4)',{'x':x});
return chl_conc;
```

After that I would pass it to collection simply adding .map(chl_oc2) to the ee.ImageCollection

This is what I wrote, except for different coefficients showed in above image. But to me there is probably something wrong.
Also in the formula you can see that I have to get the max value between band 1 and band 2 and for that I have no idea how to do it, so I just used band 2 instead but would be even better if you could help me to implement a function to choose the greatest value from 2 bands. I noted that band 1 and band 2 have two different resolutions (10m for band 1 and 60m for band 2)

Comment: You are trying to solve two different questions in one, I suggest separating them into two separate posts and try to be more specific in what you've attempted and how it's failing.

Comment: @Madeleine I only see one request: "if you could help me to implement a function to choose the greatest value from 2 bands".

Comment: I guess that depends if the mention of 'something wrong' and 'tons of mistakes'  is a request to debug the code or simply a remark. Even so I feel not enough context was given, i.e. provide a code snippet where the function is mapped over a specific imageCollection. Otherwise what is the point of the context if the question is merely how to get the max value between two bands.

Comment: To solve the max band issue, you may try something like:
maxBand = ee.Algorithms.If(band1.gt(band2),band1,band2)

Comment: @Madeleine Correct syntax would be  `var maxBand = ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(band1.gt(band2),band2,band1))` but is preferable to use `var maxBand = band1.max(band2)` because you don't need to worry about bands order.

Comment: you are correct and I apologize. It's actually two requests and you got it both right. First request was to check if the code was correct, meaning if the formula was implemented correctly, syntax-wise. The second question was about the max value between two bands, I will try to implement both of your codes and see if that works.

Comment: I answered your question for about the max value between two bands, I known you had several mistakes because you didn't select bands correctly and it was not  implemented function for adequately select band max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your affirmation that the remote sensing reflectance has to divide by pi, it is preferable to have three functions for mapping original and followings  **ImageCollections**. First of them, it prepares selected bands for correct use (dividing by pi and it is also necessary a [scale factor](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR#bands)). Second function calculates band max between B1 and B2 and includes it in a new collections as 'B12_max' and finally, your desired function. They were incorporated in following code and one value, for pixel in point (-15.857348155192721, 28.47817439021581), arbitrarily selected in the ocean, was tested with respective formulas in LibreOffice. They matched perfectly.

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point([-15.857348155192721, 28.47817439021581]);

function prepareImages(image) {
  var time = image.get('system:time_start');
  return image.divide(Math.PI*10000)
    .set('system:time_start', time);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-03')
                  .filterBounds(pt)
                  .select('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4')
                  .map(prepareImages);

var collBandMax = dataset.map(function (image) {
  var img_B1 = image
    .select('B1');

  var img_B2 = image
    .select('B2');

  var img_max_B1_B2 = img_B1.max(img_B2)
    .rename('B12_max');
    
  image = image.addBands([img_max_B1_B2]);

  var time = image.get('system:time_start');

  return image.set('system:time_start', time);

});

print("Collection with Band Max", collBandMax);

var chl_oc2 = collBandMax.map(function(image){

  var x = image.expression(
    'log10 ( Bmax / B3 )', {
      'Bmax': image.select('B12_max'),
      'B3': image.select('B3'),
  }).rename('x');
  
  var chl_conc = image.expression('10**(0.2389-1.9369*x+1.7627*x**2-3.077*x**3-0.1054*x**4)',
                             {'x':x} ).rename('chl_conc');

  var time = image.get('system:time_start');

  return chl_conc.set('system:time_start', time); });

print(chl_oc2);

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0020371832715762603,
  max: 0.018589297353133374,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.setCenter(-15.6871, 28.647, 20);

Map.addLayer(dataset.mean(), visualization, 'RGB');
Map.addLayer(chl_oc2, {}, 'chl_oc2');

//Image (3 bands)
//B1: 0.009963099437553
//B2: 0.016074649252282
//B3: 0.011681972822945
```

After running [above code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/2dadfd744fccddbecc2f00355d5442ac), I got result of following image for corroborating pixel value in that point.

[image]

In following image it can be observed that this value matched with obtained in LibreOffice spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am going to check out my code and get precious informations from your code. I wanted to ask, in the band calculations is it needed to write "float" before? Also band 1 and band 2 have different geometric resolution, is it a problem mixing different resolutions in band computations?