# Should I divide every pixel value of an image by pi when we have Rrs?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

In ([Image expression in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386363/image-expression-in-google-earth-engine)), OP wrote:

> The formula that I want to implement is the following:
> [image]
>
> Where Rrs is the remote sensing reflectance, which means I have to divide every pixel value by pi.

I'm wondering if the claim of the OP about dividing by pi is true. In other words, when I want to use above algorithm for Sentinel2 Level2-A product, should I divide every pixel value of the image by pi?